# SingleTask Activity onResume() called when starting another SingleTask activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

**Background**

I set `MainActivity` launch mode as `SingleTask`.

at `MainActivity`, I start a `SecondActivity`, which is also `SingleTask`.

I have a `MainFragment` inside `MainActivity`..

**My observation when calling `StartActivity`:**

1. `MainFragment.onPause`
2. `MainActivity.onResume`
3. `MainFragment.onResume`
4. `SecondActivity.onResume`

If I set `SecondActivity` as `SingleTop`, this behaviour will not happen..

I really don't understand why is it so?